# Using DISTINCT on joined table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: LOFTEN and LOAN_APPROVALS. What I waana do is grab the sum of the amount from the table entries.

First I am doing the following:

```
select sum(l.amount) from loften l
```

This works as it should, and gives me the result 15899000.

However, I must then do a second SQL query were I have added a search filter in my HTML form, and that data I must filter on is in the LOAN_APPROVALS table. The query below runs as it should, but it returns 110267000.

```
select sum(l.amount) from loften l
inner join loan_approvals la on la.loanid = l.loanid
```

Since I have multiple entries in the table LOAN_APPROVALS for the same loan ID (the same loan was approved by several banks), I must somehow run a distinct on that table. Much like:

```
select DISTINCT sum(l.amount) from loften l
inner join loan_approvals la on la.loanid = l.loanid
```

Of course, this is not the right way. I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone help? Much appreciated!

/Bob

Comment: I think, you should add some sample data, to show your expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to do a join?  this should work:

```
select 
     sum(amount) 
from 
     loften
where
     loanid in (
         select loanid from loan_approvals
     )
```

Comment: And you'll probably want a WHERE clause in the subquery but, yes, that should work.

Comment: @PaulSpangle yes you are right, will add BANKID in the WHERE clause and it should work perfectly.